# How Can I add data from Excel to an array/list?

Tags: python, excel

I have used python for years but almost exclusively for math/engineering work. Now I'm trying to read data from a an excel sheet and put it in an array or list to make it easy to work with in python and I'm having some trouble. Below is an example of my code, I have successfully read in the table using xlrd and I can pull data individual data points from it but when I try to put a row of data from excel into an array as shown below, I get the error **"could not convert string to float: '1F02020050'"** (The data im reading in is in this format *'1F02020050'* ). Is this because of the letters in the data?

```
import numpy as np
import xlrd 
book=xlrd.open_workbook('ManualTest2.xlsx')

sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)
Aisle=np.zeros(sheet.nrows)

for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    Aisle[i]=(sheet.cell_value(i,1))
print(Aisle)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. The code below gets the whole excel table rather than one row but is easily modifiable

import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('ManualTest2.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
print(data)